# Command for granting Access on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

What is the command for granting access to the MySQL database for all new users that want to connect?

Consider this statement:

```
CREATE USER 'java'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON javabase.* TO 'java'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Here only localhost is able to connect to the database. Can I write `'*'` instead of `'localhost'`?

Comment: I have properly formatted your code block (just needs four spaces indentation, no HTML required). It's still not quite clear what you mean, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GRANT ALL ON javabase.* TO 'java'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` would work for all hosts